# How to get data out of a Django Model and in to the HTML Template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to display information from my model `Administrateur` into my HTML Template `login.html`, but nothing is happening.

**This my Model**:

```
from django.db import models

class Administrateur(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mdp = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name
```

**This is my view**:

```
def Pseudo(request):
    administrateurs = Administrateur.objects.all()
    context={'administrateurs':administrateurs}
    return render(request, "login.html",context)
```

**This is my HTML**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% for n in administrateurs %}
{{ n.nom }}
{{ n.prenom }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure what to do with urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Do this step if you have not done it yet:
Add this to the file urls.py in the project's base directory:

```
from django.urls import include
urlpatterns = [
    # your urls
    path('login/', include('appname.urls')), #change appname to your app's name
]
```

now in your app make a new file called urls.py and add this to the file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Pseudo

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Pseudo, name="pseudo"),
]
```

then check when you go to login page (in url bar) what happens